# Getresponse form

Tags: getresponse

I bought HTML landing page theme from themeforest. The theme has opt in e-mail form. Now i want to intergrate it with getresponse - so it would work like regular getresponse web form. How can I do it?

HTML theme code is:

```
<form method="post" action="[[ PUT_THE_URL_YOUR_FORM_POSTS_TO_HERE ]]">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your GetResponse account you should go to webforms menu, choose "Create a new webform" and head on to "Plain html" tab.
There you'll see some code like the one below — which has all you need:

```
<form action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <!-- Email field (required) -->
    email: <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
    <!-- Campaign token -->
    <!-- Get the token at: https://app.getresponse.com/campaign_list.html -->
    <input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="CAMPAIGN_ID" />
    <!-- Subscriber button -->
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
```

Don't forget that besides  `action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html"` you do need to specify the campaign's id with `<input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="CAMPAIGN_ID" />` inside the form code.